# element:hover effectedElement {...} not doing anything

Tags: html, css

I have two divs. A paragraph tag sits in each div, containing some text. The code looks a little something like this:

```
<div id="box1">
  <p id="text1">Hi!</p>
</div>

<div id="box2">
  <p id="text2">Bye!</p>
</div>
```

Some CSS like this works fine:

```
#box1:hover #text1 {
  color:blue;
}
```

However, when I try to effect an element in box2 using an element in box1, it doesn't work. Something like this, for example:

```
#text1:hover #text2 {
  color:blue;
}
```

Where might I be going wrong?

Thank you.

EDIT:

The real-world code I'm working with:

HTML

```
<div id="pageContents">
            <div id="header">

                <div id="hBox">
                    <span id="pageTitle_1">FIRSTNAME<br>LASTNAME</span>
                    <div id="slider1"></div>
                </div>

                <div id="pBox">
                    <span id="projects">PAST<br>PROJECTS</span>
                    <div id="slider2"></div>
                </div>

            </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
#pBox:hover + #hBox > #pageTitle_1 {
  color:#636363;
}
```

Comment: In order for that hover style rule to work you would need an html structure as follows: `<p id="text1">Hi!<p id="text2">Bye!</p></p>` Those elements would have to be nested. CSS can't effect another element outside of the scope of its direct siblings.

Comment: ...In the way in which you intend above, at least... but there a few exceptions as nashcheez has pointed out in his answer.

Comment: By the way, this is a great example of why you should post a (simplified) version of your real-world code, not code that *"looks a little something like"* your actual code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In *css*, you cannot **traverse back** a particular selection.

*css selectors* are designed to be easy (fast) to implement for the browser. The document can be traversed once, matching elements as you go, with no need to ever go backward to adjust a match.

You can only travel forward either to your siblings or your children & grand-children and so on.
Hence something like `#text1:hover #text2` won't work.

What you can do is use the [adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) (the `+` selector) like this:

```
#box1:hover + #box2 > #text2 {
  color:blue;
}
```

**EDIT**

Unfortunately, you cannot traverse back to `#hBox` after `#pBox:hover`. There is no previous sibling selector.

This kind of selection: `#pBox:hover + #hBox > #pageTitle_1` is wrong as per the current specifications.

You have to involve Javascript/jQuery to achieve what you are trying to do here.

Refer code for a jQuery `hover()` solution:

```js
$("#pBox").hover(function() {
  $("#hBox #pageTitle_1").css("color", "red");
}, function() {
  $("#hBox #pageTitle_1").css("color", "black");
});
```

```css
#pBox:hover+#hBox>#pageTitle_1 {
  color: #636363;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pageContents">
  <div id="header">

    <div id="hBox">
      <span id="pageTitle_1">FIRSTNAME<br>LASTNAME</span>
      <div id="slider1"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="pBox">
      <span id="projects">PAST<br>PROJECTS</span>
      <div id="slider2"></div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT 2**

`+` : Adjacent sibling selector, should be used when two divs are right next to each other.

`~` : General sibling selector, should be used when the siblings are not right next to each other and can be anywhere in the dom sibling chain.

The OP's issue were solved by the *general sibling selector* cause there were other containers in between the two containers to whom the css were applied.

Refer code for the final solution:

```css
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html,
body,
div,
span,
applet,
object,
iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
a,
abbr,
acronym,
address,
big,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
em,
img,
ins,
kbd,
q,
s,
samp,
small,
strike,
strong,
sub,
sup,
tt,
var,
b,
u,
i,
center,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend,
table,
caption,
tbody,
tfoot,
thead,
tr,
th,
td,
article,
aside,
canvas,
details,
embed,
figure,
figcaption,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
output,
ruby,
section,
summary,
time,
mark,
audio,
video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}


/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
section {
  display: block;
}

body {
  line-height: 1;
  background-color: white;
}

ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

blockquote,
q {
  quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before,
blockquote:after,
q:before,
q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

#pageContents {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#header {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #404040;
}

#lowerheader {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  top: 75px;
  background-color: #66cccc;
}

#pageTitle_1 {
  font-family: 'VCR OSD MONO';
  position: fixed;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  top: 33px;
  left: 10px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in;
}

#projects:hover {
  color: white;
}

#projects {
  font-family: 'VCR OSD MONO';
  position: fixed;
  color: #636363;
  font-size: 20px;
  top: 33px;
  left: 200px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in;
}

#slider1 {
  -webkit-transition: width 1s;
  position: fixed;
  top: 60px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: white;
}

#pageTitle_1:hover+#slider1 {
  width: 130px;
  background-color: white;
}

#pageTitle_1:hover {
  color: white;
}

#slider2 {
  -webkit-transition: all 1s;
  position: fixed;
  top: 60px;
  left: 200px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #636363;
}


/*HERE!!*/

#projects:hover~#pageTitle_1 {
  color: red;
}

#projects:hover+#slider2 {
  width: 94px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <div id="pageContents">
    <div id="header">
      <div id="lowerheader"></div>

      <p id="projects">PAST<br>PROJECTS</p>
      <div id="slider2"></div>
      <p id="pageTitle_1">CASPAR<br>BROEKHUIZEN</p>
      <div id="slider1"></div>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>

<script>
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. See my edited question though, because this doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Edited. @nashcheez

Comment: Thank you again. Why did the first answer you suggested not apply in this case?

Comment: The first answer suggests an adjacent sibling selector. So it could do something like `#hBox:hover + #pBox > #projects`, but traversing backwards from `#pBox` to `hBox` is not possible, hence `#pBox:hover + #hBox > #pageTitle_1` will not be a possibility without Javascript.

Comment: In other words, if your `pBox` came *before* the `hBox` in your markup, nashcheez' original suggestion would work.

Comment: I am quite confused - I removed the hBox and pBox divs, so all the text and sliders are in the same area. Code like this works: `#projects:hover + #slider2` , but code like this doesn't `#projects:hover + #slider1`

Comment: `#projects:hover + #slider2` will work because they are under the same parent `#pBox` and `#projects` comes before `#slider2` in the DOM. `#projects:hover + #slider1` won't work cause they do not have a common parent and are not siblings.

Comment: However, I've removed the pbox and hbox divs - so shouldn't they all be siblings?

Comment: If you remove `pBox` and `hBox`, then you can select `#projects + #slider2` and `#slider1 + #projects`, but not the other way round in either case. (Read again: backward traversal is not possible).

Comment: Right. But even if I switch around the HTML so Projects sits before slider2, it still doesn't work. @nashcheez

Comment: Make me a fiddle, and I will show you all the working examples. This kind of conversation in the comment section is difficult for you to understand.

Comment: I've marked out the CSS you've helped me with at the bottom of the CSS section

Comment: Essentually, I want the Caspar Broekhuizen to turn a colour when you hover over the Past Projects.

Comment: With all due respect, this is turning into a free CSS class, which is not how Stack Overflow is supposed to work. nashcheez answer provides a solution that comes closest to what you need and links to relevant documentation. I suggest you go through some CSS selector tutorials or references and, if required, come back with a new, specific question. Of course, you are free to enjoy nashcheez' help as long as he is willing to provide it, just want to make you aware that it is clearly beyond the scope you should expect.

Comment: Of course. I fully understand that. My apologies to nascheez for not taking it upon myself to figure the rest out when he had provided the first answer, but he went above and beyond, and I am thankful for that. @domdom